# Cannot in display Amcharts in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, amcharts

I am plotting Amcharts in a particular div in my html.The problem is I receive the data through ajax and try to plot it in that div (mainchart) but I am successfully receiving the data but unable to show the graph.I am pretty sure it has something to do with the width and height of the div. But not sure how to identify it .

**HTML div is mainchart for the graph**

```
<section class="intro">

    <row>
      <div id="map" class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 left">
      </div>
      <div id ="mainchart" class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 right">
        <p>Main Chart Area</p>
      </div>
    </row>
</section>
```

**CSS class for right**

```
.right{
  display : flex;
  justify-content : center;
  align-items : center;
  background-image: url("htmlbackground.jpg");
  height : 100%;
  color : #3d231b;
}
```

JS to plot graph

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("mainchart", {
                  "type": "stock",
                  "theme": "light",
                     "dataProvider": data,

                  "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
                  "seriesField": "day",
                  "seriesValueFields": ["a", "c"],
                  "seriesGraphTemplate": {
                    "lineThickness": 2,
                    "type": "smoothedLine",
                    "useDataSetColors": false,
                    "bullet": "round"
                  },

                  "categoryAxesSettings": {
                    "minPeriod": "mm"
                  },

                  "dataSets": [{
                    "dataProvider": data,
                    "categoryField": "time"
                  }],

                  "panels": [{

                      "valueAxes": [ {
                        "title":"Values"
                        }],
                      "listeners": [{
                           "event": "drawn",
                           "method": function(e)                               

                           }
                         }

                      ],
                        "titles": [{
                              "id": "Title-1",
                              "size": 15,
                              "text": "Analysis"
                            }],

                        "stockLegend": {}
                  }],
                  "panelsSettings": {
                   "marginLeft": 50
                   },


                    "chartCursorSettings": {
                    "valueBalloonsEnabled": true
                  },

                "responsive": {
                "enabled": true
                 },

                });
```

**data**  is the data received from ajax.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things:

- First, make sure the element where the chart will be drawn to is not sharing or reuse (for lack of better words) CSS classes that are not specific to the chart.

That means you need to move the `#mainchart` div to be inside the column:

```
<row>
  <div id="map" class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 left">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 right">
    <div id ="mainchart">
      <p>Main Chart Area</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</row>
```

- Then you need to add the expected dimensions for the chart in CSS:

  ```
  #mainchart {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;}
  ```